# How can I write list<integer> in class format

Tags: java, mocking

I tried to add class format for list in 2 ways below but it doesn't work.

```
nullable((Class<List<Integer>>) new ArrayList<Integer>().getClass())
```

```
nullable(Class<List<Integer>>)
```

The `nullable` function is from `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.nullable(Class<List> clazz)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use below.

```
Class<List<Integer>> klazz =
   (Class<List<Integer>>) new ArrayList<Integer>().getClass();
// WARNING! Type safety: Unchecked cast from
//   Class<capture#1-of ? extends ArrayList> to Class<List<Integer>>
```